# Overloading constants in Perl 6

Tags: perl, operator-overloading, raku

Is it possible to overload constants in Perl 6? [Here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/prog/ch13_06.htm) is the Perl 5 example I'm looking at.

In particular I would like to get a string of the literal value used, e.g. if the code was

```
my $x = .1e-003 ;
```

I need `".1e-003"` instead of `0.0001`.

Comment: You can get close with `$x.perl` which results in `0.0001e0`. Really if that is what you want it may be better to store it as a string, and just use it as a number where you need to.

Comment: you could use sprintf to format it in scientific notation ( if you wanted a string method ), but Brad Gilbert's approach is probably best.

Comment: I think the example I give is too specific. The general intention is to be able to overload constants in Perl 6. The unique thing about `overload::constant` is that it gives me the raw string before any interpretation/simplification is done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just added such a module:

https://github.com/FROGGS/p6-overload-constant

USAGE:

```
use v6;
sub decimal { $^a.flip }
use overload::constant &decimal;

say .1e-003 # "300-e1."
```

Comment: Do I use it like an ordinary Perl module? I get `Null PMC access in get_bool()`. I am using Rakudo with Parrot built from source.

Comment: I've just tested it on rakudo on Moarvm. (which builds and runs faster anyway). But I'll also test it on Parrot and JVM, and will hopefully provide a patch soonish.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works great. I also tried returning an object and get `Unknown QAST node type Bool` but I'll have a go at debugging that myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can change how a value stringifies by mixing in an appropriate role with the [`but`](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/but) operator, ie

```
0.0001 but role { method Str { ".1e-003" } }
```

which can be shortened to

```
0.0001 but ".1e-003"
```

Note that providing a method [`Stringy`](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Stringy) instead of [`Str`](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/Str) might actually be more appropriate from a semantic point of view, but I do not think Rakudo as of today handles that distinction correctly in all case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything like `overload::constant` exists in the spec or the existing libraries, but it should be possible to write it using [macros](http://perlcabal.org/syn/S06.html#Macros) by looking in the AST for the type of literal that you're interested in, and replacing it with an object constructor or whatever you need.

Cleaner, perhaps, would be to wrap each one of these constants in a macro invocation, instead of spanning the whole program with one.

Comment: This looks interesting. I get an `AST` object with `my $ast = quasi { 1+2 } ;` for example but I can't find how to proceed. It says [here](http://doc.perl6.org/type/AST) that there are no APIs defined yet, so perhaps this is not possible at the moment.